# Given 2 real numbers $a < b$ , let $d(x,[a,b]) = min\{|x-y| : a \leq y \leq b \}$ for $-\infty\leq x \leq \infty$

Tags: functions, real-numbers

Then the function $f(x) = \frac{d(x,[0,1])}{d(x,[0,1])+d(x,[2,3])}$ satisfies

(A)  $0 \leq x < \frac{1}{2} $ for every $x$

(B) $0 < x < 1$ for every $x$

(C) $f(x) = 0$ if $2\leq x \leq 3$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $0 \leq x \leq  1$

(D) $f(x) = 0$ if $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $2 \leq x \leq  3$.

I think the answer should be (D). Since for $0\leq x \leq 1$, then $ d(x,[0,1])=min\{|x-y|: 0 \leq y \leq 1 =0\}=0$ , so $f(x)=0$. For $2\leq x \leq 3$, $ d(x,[2,3])=min\{|x-y|: 2 \leq y \leq 3 \}=0$  , so $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x-1+0}=1.$

Comment: I do not think your affirmation is correct. (A) and (B) provide inconsistent information, as well as (C) and (D).

Comment: Are you asking which one of the statements is true?  What have you tried?

Comment: D is the answer as I feel after working it out